# Crawling a large directory with wget with two links pointing at the same thing

Tags: linux, wget, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a directory on a website and basically download everything in it. The structure is simple enough(but there are also multiple folders), but there is one thing that makes wget choke up. The source looks something like this:

```
<a href="index.php?path=/blah/whatever&download=resource.txt"><img... /></a> .... <a href="/blah/whatever/resource.txt">resource.txt"</a>
```

Both of the links work, but they are both the same thing. So wget will download the same file twice. How can I make wget ignore the first one? Or if you have a better crawler suggestion that works in Linux(or OpenBSD) then suggest it  instead

I've tried using the reject list as so:

```
wget -r -R index.php\*\&download\* http://url
```

but this doesn't seem to actually do anything. It will still download the duplicate URLs

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like... just -R index.php*
?as that sounds like the other links will still work fine?

Comment: Actually I figured out my problem is a caveat to wget. My pattern was correct(except for a missing `\*` at the beginning) but wget will download even files in it's reject list. It will just delete them right after downloading them for whatever reason.

Comment: oh, haha... gotcha. Inefficient but good enough I guess

Comment: From the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html#Types-of-Files): _Note, too, that query strings (strings at the end of a URL beginning with a question mark (‘?’) are not included as part of the filename for accept/reject rules, even though these will actually contribute to the name chosen for the local file. It is expected that a future version of Wget will provide an option to allow matching against query strings._

Comment: Well, thankfully even for the horrible feature of downloading every file twice, wget is handling the download correctly in the final file structure